# Defining a package with its sub units in Package Name?

Tags: package, ada

I have run across code in [`Ncurses`](https://www.invisible-island.net/ncurses/Ada95.html) which defines packages with dot, "." subunits in the name, like this:
Package body example.subunit1.subunit1 is
....
....
end example;

Would I not just name the package "example" only and then later  with example.subunit1; use example.subunit1;

OR does older Ada code (as found in Ncurses) have syntax to put a package's subunits in the package name?

Comment: In any Ada standard AFAIK, if package B is declared within package A then the full name of B is A.B and that name can be used anywhere the unqualified name B is used, whether B is a separate subunit or not. Perhaps you can give a fuller part of some example, including both the declaration and the start of the body of the subunit? Your present example seems invalid because it should end with "end example.subunit1.subunit2".

Comment: I've cited the code above; please edit as necessary; see also [_Hierarchical Packages_](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/Ada_For_The_CPP_Java_Developer/chapters/07_Packages.html?highlight=child%20package#hierarchical-packages).

Comment: Thanks very much Nicklas; you have answered my question perfectly. To date, my Ada code, self learning Ada,  has not used sub packages within a parent package, so the naming convention threw me a little. I will have to look at the parent, encapsulating package for the error. Tks again.